# How do I determine the number of arguments of a user-supplied function?

Tags: r

I have a function `myfun` which among other arguments has one that is a user supplied function, say `f`. This function may have any number of arguments, including maybe none. Here is a simple example:

```
myfun = function(f, ...) { f()}
```

Now calls to `myfun` might be

```
myfun( f=function() rnorm(10) )
myfun( f=function(m) rnorm(10, m) )
```

I don't want to use the ellipse argument `...` inside of `f`, so my question is whether there is any other way to determine inside of `myfun` how many arguments the function `f` has? If `f` has no arguments it is then passed to the Rcpp routine `doA.cpp`, but if it has one or more arguments it is passed to `doB.cpp`. So I need to know inside `myfun` which it is.

Here is a toy example which hopefully makes it clearer what I am after:

```
myfun = function(f) { 
   numarg = number.of.arguments(f)
   if(numarg==0) return(doA.cpp(f))
   else return(doB.cpp(f))
   
}
```

so I need a "function" number.of.arguments, that is some way to determine numarg.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your specific use-case, your best bet might be to query the [formal arguments](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/formals.html) of `f`. However, note that there are several caveats with this method, which I note below.

```
f = function (f) {
    if (length(formals(f)) == 0L) {
        doA.cpp(f)
    } else {
        doB.cpp(f)
    }
}
```

The caveats are that `formals` does not work for primitive functions: `formals(mean)` works, but `formals(sum)` returns `NULL`. Furthermore, `formals` counts `...` as a single argument. So if you want to handle `...` differently you'll have to do this manually:

```
if ('...' %in% names(formals(f))) {
    # `...` is present
} else {
    # `...` is not present
}
```

---

A more robust method when the user supplies the arguments is to find the length of the `...` args via [`...length()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dots.html).

You could then pass the `...` arguments to `doB.cpp` inside a list, for instance:

```
myfun = function(f, ...) {
    if (...length() == 0L) {
        doA.cpp(f)
    } else {
        doB.cpp(f, list(...))
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said before, I would prefer not to use the ... construct. At least not if there is another way to determine the number of arguments of the user-supplied function, numarg in my latest toy example

Comment: @WolfgangRolke I think I see what you mean now. So `doB.cpp` will supply its own arguments for calling `f`, rather than taking them from the caller?

Comment: Yes, that's right. At some point inside of the cpp functions there will be  a call to f and I need to know whether it is just f() or f(x), where is a data set already available, not supplied by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Konrad's is just what I need! Also, I learned about the formals function, which I had not seen before. Its limitations as discussed by Konrad won't matter for my case because the functions are ones the users have to write anyway, and I won't use ... . So, thanks!

Wolfgang

Answer (score -2):

This is what I may code in R.

```
myfun = function(f, ...) { f(...)}
myfun( f=function(m) rnorm(10, m), m )
```

After getting comment from @Wolfgang Rolke, the question becomes better understood. Here is my second attempt.

```
myfun = function(f, ...) { 
    argg <- c(as.list(environment()), list(...))
    numarg=length(argg)
    if (numarg==1) { return( f()) }
    if (numarg==2) { return(f(argg[[2]])) }
}

myfun( f=function() rnorm(10) )
myfun( f=function(m=2) rnorm(10, m) )
```

To easily verify the result, one may do the following:

```
myfun( f=function() mean(rnorm(10))) # it returns something like 0.07599287 
myfun( f=function(m=10) mean(rnorm(10, m))) # it returns 9.49364
```

Comment: Except that OP explicitly said that he does not want to use `...`.

Comment: Executing myfun( f=function(m) rnorm(10, m) ) causes an error . This was why I said what I would do in R.

Comment: A bit more about what I am trying to do: Inside myfun if f has no arguments it is then passed to the Rcpp routine doA.cpp, but if it has one or more arguments it is passed to doB.cpp. So I need to know inside myfun which it is.

Comment: Please refer my second attempt.

Comment: Thanks SBMVNO, but this solution doesn't work. Running the examples as is numarg is always 1. For it to help me in the second example it should be 2. Running myfun( f=function(m=2) rnorm(10, m), m=6 ) now numarg is 2, but as I said before I don't want to use the ellipse ... notation. The reason for this is that I am trying to keep the functions as simple as possible because I anticipate them to be used by people who are not very familiar with R.

Comment: by running myfun( f=function() mean(rnorm(10))) , we get  0.07599287. and by running myfun( f=function(m=10) mean(rnorm(10, m))), we get 9.788659. Note that there is no '...' inside f.